# How can I iterate a Map within a Map within a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, hashmap

I have a Map within a Map within a Map. The format is `HashMap<String, Map>` A sample data:

```
deviceName={commandName={dataKey1=[dataValue1], dataKey2=[dataValue2]}}
```

The way it's setup is `deviceName` is the `key` and `commandName` is the value for it. To keep it simple there is only one now but there could be more than one command. At the second iteration `commandName` is the `key` and `{dataKey1=[dataValue1], dataKey2=[dataValue2]}` is the value. In the third iteration `dataKey1` is the key and `dataValue1` is the value(it's an arrayList).

I can iterate through one but i am not sure how to do this.

```
public void analyseVersion(Map cmd) {

    Iterator deviceIT = cmd.keySet().iterator();
    while (deviceIT.hasNext()) {
        String deviceName = (String) deviceIT.next();
        //Map<String, Map> cmd = (Map<String, Map>) cmd.get(deviceName);//This will not work.
        //At this point I want to iterate through each command and for each command iterate through each data set.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using generics for the declarations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo jtahlborn, abstraction is your friend

```
public class Data
   private Map<String, Object> attributes

public class Command
   private Map<String, Data> data;

public class Device
   private Map<String, Command> commands;

// in main, etc
for (Entry<String, Command> commandEntry : device.getCommandEntries())
{
  for (Entry<String, Data> dataEntry : commandEntry.getValue().getDataEntries())
  {
    for (Entry<String, Object> attributeEntry : dataEntry.getValue().getAttributeEntries())
       // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to maintain this structure, you should be using something like this for your cmd map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,List<String>>>>
```

however, i'd recommend wrapping these maps in classes to make your life easier and your code *much* cleaner.